# Node anti affinity not working on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried to run the nginx ingress service on multiple hosts using this config

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-addon: ingress-nginx.addons.k8s.io
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
        k8s-addon: ingress-nginx.addons.k8s.io
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/affinity: >
          {
            "podAntiAffinity": {
              "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [{
                "labelSelector": {
                  "matchExpressions": [
                    { "key": "app", "operator": "In", "values": ["ingress-nginx"] }
                  ]
                },
                "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname",
                "weight": 100
              }]
            }
          }
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
          name: ingress-nginx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
            - --nginx-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
```

however k8s has scheduled two pods in the same node, is there something wrong with it? I'm using kubernetes 1.5.2

Update: If i use `required` instead of `preferred` all the three pods gives `failed to fit in any node fit failure summary on nodes : MatchInterPodAffinity (3), PodToleratesNodeTaints (1)` at first but after a minute or two they're correctly scheduled on separate hosts

Answer (score 0):

its working correctly. You need to create a service first. If you create a Service for that Deployment first, Kubernetes will spread your pods across nodes.

Corresponding section in the documentation: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/config-best-practices/#services

Replication sets take the place of the controllers but i believe the service still works the same.

Comment: I have a service for that deployment too, but it's not spread across multiple hosts, also aren't replication controller deprecated in favor of the deployments?
I've to add another update to the question

Comment: I've added the behavior when I set `required` instead of `preferred`